# Ejs partial header and footer file working in one file and not the other (same directory level)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

I'm currently working on setting up a view page for a post on the home page of a website. Both the home and view page are using the same header and footer files. They are both on the same directory level. One is working and the other isn't. The errors being displayed seem to relate to the script and link tags in the header and footer file.

Error types: (custom scripts and links also throw these errors)

5ab70c4e84fa1b212efa0145:5 
GET http://localhost:5000/home/scripts/lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED
5ab70c4e84fa1b212efa0145:1

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:5000/home/scripts/lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

5ab70c4e84fa1b212efa0145:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:5000/home/stylesheets/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

My header and footer partials are as follows:

Header:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="far fa-heart"></i> The Beanie Boo Network</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                  </form>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <% if(!currentUser){ %>
                        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
                    <% } else { %>
                        <li><a href="#"><%=currentUser.username%></a></li>
                        <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                    <% } %>    
                  </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
              </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>

        <div class="container">
```

Footer:

```
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

file it works in: (full)

```
<% include ../partials/header %>

    <header class="jumbotron">
        <div>
            <h1>Beanie Booboard</h1>
            <h4>Keep up to date with whats going on on The Beanie Boo Network</h4>
        </div>
    </header>

    <% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="caption col-sm-6">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h2><%=post.title%></h2>
                        <p><%=post.content.substring(0, 50)%>...</p>
                        <p><em><%=post.author%></em></p>
                        <p><%=post.created.toDateString()%></p>
                        <a href="/home/<%=post._id%>"class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail-img col-sm-6">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<%=post.image%>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% }); %>

<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

file it does not work in: (full)

```
<% include ../partials/header %>


<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

What I'm trying to figure out and understand is why is one file throwing the errors and the other isn't, how can i avoid this error in the future, and fix it if it is to arise?

Comment: have you tried `<%- include ../partials/header %>`

Comment: chnage it to `<%- include('../partials/header'); %>`

Answer (score 1):

Try using
<%- include(“partials/header”); -%> for the header
And
<%- include(“partials/footer”); -%> for the footer

Comment: Since it’s already in a partials folder in and in order to access that file as you would access other files in a folder using the folder name then, / , then the file name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

the solution is quite strange as it doesnt explain why it was working in one page and not the other. But i changed the script and links tags a little. I removed the type attribute from both the link and script tags in the header and footer files and added "/" in front of the file paths. Nothing changed in the one that was already working, but the one that wasnt working now works.

if anyone has any idea of the inner workings i would really appreciate and explanation. thanks.